# How to set a variable outside of a loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, scope

I'm trying to set a variable outside of the scope of the current loop.

My scenario is this: I have 2 lists. One containing a list of comment objects, and each comment has a reference to a user id. My second list contains all the user objects, based on the users id.

What I am trying to do is iterate through each comment, and then modify the comment object within the list to contain the users name, so that when I pass the list of comments back, it has the name embedded.

So far, this how I am trying to achieve this:

```
# iterate through the comments and add the display name to the comment obj
for comment in comments:
    # Create the user to use later
    user = None

    # Iterate the comment_users and get the user who matches the current comment.
    for comment_user in comment_users:

        if comment_user['_id'] is comment['created_by']:
            user = comment_user  # this is creating a new user in the for comment_user loop
            break

    print(user)

    # get the display name for the user
    display_name = user['display_name']

    # Add the user display name to the comment
    comment.user_display_name = display_name
```

Now, from what I am starting to understand from Python's scope, is that the user = comment_user line in the second for loop is creating a new user variable within the scope of the second for loop, which is ignoring the user variable defined in the first for loop.

I'm using Python 3, so I thought that the nonlocal keyword would be the way to go, but I'm not sure if that is just for functions or not, as I couldn't get it to work.

So, I was wondering if anyone could provide a way to achieve this? Is there a more '*pythonic*' way to achieve this?

Comment: No, this isn't what's happening. Python does not have block scope.

Comment: I don't think you have a problem with scopes, but why don't you just set the comment's username inside the `if` block?

Comment: Thanks for the help on the block scope, helpful to know for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is your use of `is`. Try this code:

```
for comment in comments:
    for comment_user in comment_users:
        if comment_user['_id'] == comment['created_by']:
            comment.user_display_name = comment_user['display_name']
            break
```

This problem occurs when you are (incorrectly) using `is` to compare `string` objects. The equality operator (`==`) checks if the contents of the two strings are the same, whereas `is` operator actually checks if they are the *same* object. If the strings are [interned](http://selcuk.ayguney.com/2014/03/string-interning/), they may give the same result, but generally speaking you should never use `is` for string comparison.

Comment: Thanks! It was the use of the `is` keyword. Now I need to go read up on this and make sure I'm not misusing it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think a more pythonic way would be to make `comment_user` a dictionary that has the `_id` as key, so that you don't have to loop over the list but can just do

```
for comment in comments:
    comment.user_display_name = comment_user[comment['created_by']]['display_name']
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My comment_users is a pymongo cursor, so I just thought it would have been easier to try and loop through both. I'll have a look into making it a dictionary.